# Prob 6, Sec 7 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: The existence of an injection of a superset into the set means the sets have the same cardinality?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $A$ and $B$ be two sets such that $B \subset A$ and there is an injection $f \colon A \to B$. Then how to show that $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality?

Munkres' Hint:

We define $A_1 \colon= A$, $B_1 \colon= B$, and, for $n > 1$, we define $A_n \colon= f(A_{n-1})$ and $B_n \colon= f(B_{n-1})$.

Thus, we have 
$$B_1 = B \subset A_1 = A$$
and 
$$A_2 = f(A_1) = f(A) \subset B = B_1,$$
that is, 
$$A_2 \subset B_1 \subset A_1.$$
Now if, for any +ive integer $n \geq 1$, we have 
$$B_{n+1} \subset B_n \subset A_n, $$
then we also have
$$B_{n+2} = f(B_{n+1}) \subset f(B_n) = B_{n+1}$$
and 
$$B_{n+1} = f(B_n) \subset f(A_n) = A_{n+1},  $$
that is, 
$$B_{n+2} \subset B_{n+1} \subset A_{n+1}.$$
Hence using induction we can conclude that
$$A_{n+1} \subset B_n \subset A_n \ \mbox{ for each } \ n \in \mathbb{N}.$$
That is, 
$$A_1 \supset B_1 \supset A_2 \supset B_2 \supset A_3 \supset B_3 \supset \ldots.$$

Now let the map $h \colon A \to B$ be defined as follows:
$$ h(x) \colon= 
\begin{cases} 
f(x) \ & \mbox{ if } \ x \in A_n - B_n \ \mbox{ for some } \ n; \\
x \ & \mbox{ otherwise}. 
\end{cases}
$$
Munkres claims that this map $h$ is a bijection. How do we show this?

Injectivity of $h$:

Suppose $a, x \in A$ such that $h(a) = h(x)$. We need to show that $a=x$.

If there exist $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a \in A_m - B_m$ and $x \in A_n - B_n$, then we must have 
$$f(a) = h(a) = h(b) = f(b),$$
which implies $a = b$.

On the other hand, if $a \not\in A_n - B_n$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \not\in A_n - B_n$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then we have 
$$a = h(a) = h(b) = b.$$

How to show that $a = b$ in the following situation?

There exists some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a \in A_m - B_m$ but 
$x \not\in A_n - B_n$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Surjectivity of $h$:

Let $b \in B$.

Then $b \in A$.

If $b \not\in A_n - B_n$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then we have 
$b = h(b)$.

On the other hand, if, for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $b \in A_k - B_k$, then let $k$ be the smallest such positive integer.

If $k = 1$, then we have $b \in A - B$, which is a contradiction as $b \in B$, by our hypothesis. So we must have $k > 1$; rather, $k \geq 2$.

As $b \in A_k - B_k$ and as $A_k \subset B_{k-1}$, so we must have $b \in B_{k-1}$. What next?

Comment: isn't this like [Schroder-Bernsteintheorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem)

Comment: Lol, yes remarkably like Schroder-Bernstein. You have an injection $A\to B$, and an injection $B\to A$ (the inclusion map).

Comment: @Mirko, This is part (a) of the problem. Part (b) is to use part (a) to prove the full Schoder-Bernstein theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked me to answer here: http://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/chapter-1/section-7-countable-and-uncountable-sets/problem-6-solution/#comment-2390104583.

Step 1. We show the inclusions $A_1\supset B_1\supset A_2\supset B_2\supset\cdots$, you have already shown it in the question.

Step 2. We show that $h$ is well-defined. Indeed, for all $x\in A$, $h(x)\in B$, as if $x\in A−B=A_1−B_1$ then $h(x)=f(x)\in B$, otherwise $x\in B$, and $h(x)\in \{x,f(x)\}\subset B$, so that $h(x)\in B$.

Step 3. We show that $h$ is bijective. We split all of $A$ into "slices" $C_n=A_n−B_n$ and the rest $X=A−\cup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}C_n$.

(a) All slices and $X$ are pairwise disjoint. $X$ is disjoint from any $C_n$ by definition. Further, for $m>n$, we have $C_m\subset A_m$ (by definition), $A_m\subset B_n$ by Step 1, $B_n\cap C_n=\emptyset$ by definition. Overall, we have $C_m\cap C_n=\emptyset$.

(b) The restriction of $h$ to $C_n$ is a bijection $h_n:C_n\rightarrow C_{n+1}$ because $f|A_n:A_n\rightarrow A_{n+1}$ and  $f|B_n:B_n\rightarrow B_{n+1}$ where $B_k\subset A_k$ are bijections.

(c) The restriction of $h$ to X is the identity function.

Since the image sets of the functions $h_n$ and $h|X$ are pairwise disjoint (by (a), (b) and (c)), $A=X\cup_{n\in \mathbb{Z}_+}C_n$ and $h(A)=X\cup_{n\in \mathbb{Z}_+}C_{n+1}=A−C_1=B$, we conclude that $h$ is injective and surjective, i.e. bijective.

Comment: thank you so much for being so helpful, but can you please also answer my question in its specific framework? Of course, there could be different approaches to reaching the same proof, but I would also like to have the proof picking up from where I've gotten to.

Comment: the very last paragraph of your answer is perhaps in need of elaboration or rephrasing.

Comment: Instead of considering each case separately, what is done here you partition $A$ into disjoint union of $C_n$ and $X$, $B$ into disjoint union of $X$ and $C_n$ for $n>1$, and show that $h$ restricted to each $C_n$ or $X$ is bijective, where the corresponding images form the partition of $B$. In other words, suppose $f:A\rightarrow B$, $A=A_1\cup A_2$, $B=B_1\cup B_2$, $A_1$ and $A_2$ as well as $B_1$ and $B_2$ are disjoint, and f maps bijectively $A_i$ onto $B_i$, can you see that $f$ is bijective? In our case $A$ and $B$ are partitioned into a countable number of subsets.

Comment: Regarding the last sentence, I believe you see that $h$ is surjective. To show that it is injective, assume $h(x)=h(y)=z$, then $z$ is in $X$ or some $C_n$, $n>1$, correspondingly, both $x$ and $y$ have to be in $X$ or $C_{n-1}$, but in either case $h$ restricted to these sets is bijective, so that $x=y$.

Comment: You keep asking questions here, and leave them "open". If this answers your question, you should probably mark this as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you didn't finish proving surjectivity of $h$, let me complete it. You want to prove that, that for any $b \in B$ such that $b \in (A_k - B_k)$ for some positive integer $k>1$, there exists some $\alpha \in A \; |\,h(\alpha)=b $. 
Due to $A_k=f(A_{k-1})$, $B_k = f(B_{k-1})$ and $f$ is an injective function,$A_k - B_k = f(A_{k-1}) - f(B_{k-1}) = f(A_{k-1} - B_{k-1})$. Then, $b\in f(A_{k-1} - B_{k-1})$, i.e, there exists some $\alpha\in A_{k-1}\subseteq A$ such that $f(\alpha)=b$ when $\alpha \in (A_{k-1} - B_{k-1})$, and $h(\alpha)=b$. This should complete the surjectivity proof you started.